# Is the [activity] tag defined too narrowly?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, scope

Currently, the tag wiki for [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) says this:

> [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is the main UI component of the Android System. It represents one particular thing a user can do, one screen of the application.

Really?  That's the only thing an *activity* can refer to?

Shouldn't this tag really be [android-activity]?

Note: Although [intent](/questions/tagged/intent) doesn't have a tag wiki, it has the same problem.  I could see how you might have these tags on an Android-specific site, but on StackOverflow these tags seem...well, too broad and generic to apply to concepts that are so specific.

Comment: I don't know much about "activity" in the context of Android (or any other framework that would use the name) but in the general sense, we could argue that it is a meta tag by itself.  I would much rather see it as [tag:android-activity] (with appropriate variant for each other use) instead of plain old vanilla [tag:activity].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem like the vast *majority* of [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) questions are in fact about Android, although clearly the word has broader meaning and applies to a few other less-popular concepts (gwt, <del>WWF</del> WF).

It's too bad you can't do a mass rename for all questions tagged [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) AND [android](/questions/tagged/android).  Perhaps a tag merge/rename, followed by a hand-sorting of the non-Android questions?

Comment: +1, WF4 is based around an Activity.

Comment: Right. So should you have an `[activity]` tag with multiple meanings in its tag wiki, or should you have a `[wf-activity]` tag, and an `[android-activity]` tag, and a...

Comment: @Robert: The latter. Get rid of the ambiguous tags, replace them with unambiguous ones.

Comment: Better than a dev merge and resort is to find the ones that don't have android issues and retag them first. IDs would likely be enough for a dev to avoid a bump