# General rules for multi tags and concatenated tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While reading the topic about [cleaning up the android tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag) there was also a [comment from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119996/138437) to the usage of concatenated tags like [android-layout](/questions/tagged/android-layout). Jeff said that [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [layout](/questions/tagged/layout) should be used as multiple tags are possible.

I asked why the reality goes in the other direction referring to [android-intent synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-intent/synonyms) but I didn't get any answer so that is why I ask here.

I think Jeff is right and we should use the multiple tagging instead the combined tags but before I start to edit the tags, I was wondering if there is already a rule and if not, if we could formulate one. Also there is help needed from moderators as some automatic tagging needed to be turned off/on depending on the final decision.

PS: I don't want to start a war about tagging :)

PPS: seeing the tag [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) as a perfect example on how hard it will be to draw a line when a tag is useful and should be concatenated and when not...

Comment: Is this really the way to go? `[layout]` doesn't really make sense, `[android]` is too broad. `[android-layout]` perfectly describes what the question is about.

Comment: I think we can't dismiss a meta tag like [android]. How would you be able to monitor platforms this way? And in combination [android] and [layout] are working perfect. My preferred tag is [android] and it wouldn't make sense to add all [android-*] tags to the list, just to get the platform monitored/preferred, right?

Comment: Hm. I guess so. Maybe I'm coming from the wrong background where you find errors like `[virtual] [machine]`, etc.

Comment: Well, that is exactly the point I made in my PPS :) It is hard to draw the line and that is the reason for this question.

Comment: In the situation you describe, wouldn't it make sense to tag using _both_ `android` and `android-layout`? I don't particularly like tags like `layout` because they're pretty much meaningless and _could_ apply to many different platforms (Java for example). `android-layout` on the other hand applies to well.. Android layout :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the reasoning behind the  [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) and [android-layout](/questions/tagged/android-layout) tags is that the Android community was co-opting the [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) and [layout](/questions/tagged/layout) tags to mean something [very specific to Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97197), even though these tags were being used on other questions having nothing to do with Android. The Tag Wikis for these tags even contained language that said they were specific to Android.

To solve the problem, the different meanings for [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) and [layout](/questions/tagged/layout) were separated into their own tags, such as [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) and [workflow-activity](/questions/tagged/workflow-activity).  To make the whole thing consistent, [android-layout](/questions/tagged/android-layout), [android-intent](/questions/tagged/android-intent), and a few others, were added to the mix.

---

One reason you might want to make make specific tags is so that you can follow them (you can't follow pairs of tags).  Also, you can't make a Tag Wiki for tag pairs.

That said, it's still possible to search on tag pairs, and this process is *very effective* for finding subsets of questions that are specific to a particular concept like [Android Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+layout).

Comment: Interesting and logical point of view. Thanks!