# Should the "activity" tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Is [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) useful? Its wiki:

> Activity has multiple meanings. For Android activities, use the more specific [android-activity] tag. For Windows Workflow Foundation activities, use the more specific [workflow-activity] tag.

It basically says "This is not the tag you're looking for" and "You really want to use one of these instead".

There has already been discussion of various issues with the tag, but it doesn't seem any of the [older](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97197/167443) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114470/167443) has led to [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) being any more useful.

I can't think of any question that could be tagged with this tag alone. Should it be burninated?

If not, would it be possible to blacklist it so that it continues to exist as a signpost ot [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) and [workflow-activity](/questions/tagged/workflow-activity) but is not usable on a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently [256 questions tagged `activity` but not `android`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity+-android). That's about 5% of the total number of questions tagged [activity](/questions/tagged/activity).

This is small enough to show to allow two possibilities:

- Decide that since [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) is overwhelmingly used for Android activities, this is its only meaning. Merge [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) into [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity).
- Merge [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) into [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity), then remove the synonym (so that only [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) remains) and blacklist [activity](/questions/tagged/activity).

Either way, those [questions tagged `activity` but not `android`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity+-android) first need to be manually retagged — either to [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) if they're about Android, or [workflow-activity](/questions/tagged/workflow-activity) or whatever tag is relevant. As usual, if you edit a post, don't just do the minimum retagging: also fix any issues with grammar, formatting, etc.

Comment: P.S. [tag:activity] is now a synonym of [tag:android-activity].

Answer (score 3):

If this signpost didn't exist, would people know about [android-activity](/questions/tagged/android-activity) or [workflow-activity](/questions/tagged/workflow-activity)?

Just because it's a signpost doesn't mean it's useless.

Additionally, by not having any questions attached to this tag, it will self-destruct.

Comment: Fair point. I *would* argue that typing "activity" into the tag area would bring up those tags as suggestions, but workflow-activity doesn't make the suggestion cut.

Comment: @Jim If [tag:activity] was removed, [tag:workflow-activity] would become #6.